# Java: Fast 2D Hit Detection for Mouse Click

Tags: java, graphics

### Context

I am using Java Graphics2D.

I am drawing a bunch of shapes.

I want to be able to do fast hit detection -- when the mouse clicks an object, I want to know what object is clicked.

### More Details:

I would like to do this at the level of *fill* detection. I.e. if I have a circle, I don't want hit detection on the bounding box of the circle, I want hit detection on the inside of the Circle.

For strokes/lines/fonts, I'm okay with doing hit detection against the box (rather than the black part of the letters).

### Question:

What APIs should I be using to set this up? [And out of courisity, what algoritm does Java use / what is it's big-OH running time?]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ask each Shape with [`shape.contains(point)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#contains%28java.awt.geom.Point2D%29)?

That's O(number of shapes), but you probably don't need anything faster. Assuming the hit test on a shape takes 1 microsecond, and you have 100,000 shapes, you can still process 10 clicks a second ...

Comment: There's not some type of quad tree algorithm where the screen is split, and it binary searches?

Comment: Of course there is, but I don't think you'll find it ready-made in the Java API. You may of course look for libraries implementing something like this - but do you need to? Do you really have that many shapes or so little cpu that you need to optimize this? Put differently, drawing that many shapes will be far more expensive than hit-testing them with the approach above.

Comment: 1 microsecond is quite an optimistic prognosis for general (non-rectangular) shape. One cache miss is like 80-100ns alone.

Comment: I consider 1 microsecond a reasonable estimate: All implementations of Shape.contains I looked at first check whether the point falls withing the (cached) bounding box. This is likely to eliminate most shapes from consideration.

Comment: there has been years since i did raw graphics/drawing stuff but Path2D didn't check boundaries.

Comment: You're right. Let's say 10 microseconds? That still leaves 10,000 shapes at 10 clicks per second.

Comment: I'm implementing something like xfig, in Java. Lots of shapes will be drawn.